# Mongo Shell is broken

Tags: linux, mongodb, shell, amazon-web-services, amazon-linux

I am on Amazon Linux.

My Mongo Shell is broken. I spent much time trying to solve the issue without succeeding.

When I launch mongo, nothing happen.mongo

[image]

I have few thoughts, maybe I erase mongo since the size is zero
[image]

I use the following command to start mongod, and I have no issue.

sudo nohup mongod --config /etc/mongodb.conf &

And below is my config

[image]

Thank you so much if you could help me with that.

Comment: The proper answer to this is "reinstall whatever package provided your `mongo` executable". Reinstalling a package on Linux-distro-X is more of a [unix.se] question than a StackOverflow one.

Answer (score 1):

Issue solved thank you so much Charles Duffy. Your little tip helped to me to figure it out. I first removed the package

```
sudo yum remove -y mongodb-org-shell
```

Then I reinstalled it and it worked

```
sudo yum install -y mongodb-org-shell
```